# How do I get certain vaules of an array in js by checking the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I'm new to javascript and kind of stuck with the problem.
I want to create some checkboxes and when I select and submit some of them, I want to get the associated output from an array. In my case, I can only send some data by hard coding in the "value" attribute of the "input" element. But, I want to send the data from the array "names".

Can anyone please help me out?

```js
function submit() {
  var names = ["zihan", "zihan", "zihan", "masud", "masud", "shakil"];
  var arrayNAME = [];
  var tblName = document.getElementById("tblName");
  var check = tblName.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (check[i].checked) {
      arrayNAME.push(check[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (arrayNAME.length > 0) {
    alert(`Selected value: ${arrayNAME.join(",")}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tblName">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="zahid" value="zahid">
      <label for="zahid"> Zahid </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="masud" value="masud">
      <label for="masud"> Masud </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="jihan" value="jihan jihan jihan">
      <label for="jihan"> Jihan </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="submit()"> Submit </button>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is not clear, could you explain more ?

Comment: As you see the code, by checking the checkboxes and pressing the submit button, I'm getting the values I inserted in the "value" property. Like, "value='zahid' ". But, I want to pass those values from the array named "names".

Comment: but, what is the relation between the checkboxes and the names array ? In other words, how could we know which value to print from the names array when a certain checkbox or more is/are checked ?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I can make three arrays for three checkboxes and call the certain one.

Comment: because you have only three checkboxes and more than 3 values in the array that's whay I asked. Anyway, for example, if you check the second checkbox, the printed value should be the second in the array ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. That is something I want to do..

Comment: I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select all the checkboxes and then depending on their index in the page and if a checkbox is checked append the desired value to the final array from "names" array.

```js
function submit() {
  // dummy values to facilate the recognition of the checked input(s)
  const names = ['checkbox one', 'checkbox two', 'checkbox three'],
    arrayNAME = [],
    tblName = document.getElementById("tblName"),
    check = tblName.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  // push the "names" values to "arrayNAME" of the checked inputs
  check.forEach((el, idx) => el.checked && arrayNAME.push(names[idx]));
  // for a better UX on the site (SO), I'd use "console.log" instead of "alert"
  arrayNAME.length && console.log(`Selected value: ${arrayNAME.join(",")}`);
}
```

```html
<table id="tblName">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="zahid" value="zahid">
      <label for="zahid"> Zahid </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="masud" value="masud">
      <label for="masud"> Masud </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="jihan" value="jihan jihan jihan">
      <label for="jihan"> Jihan </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="submit()"> Submit </button>
```